# Is it possible to have two different Function Region for staging and production environment in the same project in Vercel

Tags: vercel

I had my staging and production deployment in the same project by using different GitHub branches, they require different function regions, for example: my staging database region is different than my production database region, therefore I want to host the website in different regions also.

Is it possible to have a different Function Region for the staging and production deployment? Many thanks.